# python3 in a virtualenv still uses library in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have successfully created a virtual environment with `virtualenvwrapper` using python3 at `/usr/local/bin/python3` as default interpreter. My system python is python2.7

I can't use pip3 in this virtual environment because it keeps looking inside the default `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`

```
(python3.3.3)╭ ➜ xxx@xxx:~VIRTUAL_ENV/bin  
╰ ➤ pip3.3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxx/virtualenv/python3.3.3/bin/pip3.3", line 7, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.basecommand import command_dict, load_command, load_all_commands, command_names
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.baseparser import parser, ConfigOptionParser, UpdatingDefaultsHelpFormatter
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/baseparser.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 45
    def _bypass_ensure_directory(name, mode=0777):
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Am I forgetting something?

I've also tried to install python3 into a custom directory inside `/opt` but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. My system `$PYTHONPATH` contains `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` so I simply removed it from the path and everything is now working properly.